# Embed video on product page below description using attribute

Tags: magento-1.9

I've created attribute **product_video** with scope **global**, type **text field** and **used in product listing** turned on.

Now I've added this code in view.phtml

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_videoId, 'product_video') ?>
?color=ba9344&badge=0" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But the number (video-id) I add in the back-end at a product, doesn't get loaded on front-end. Anybody know a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code ,

```
$this->getProduct()->getProductVideo();
```

instead of

```
$this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_videoId, 'product_video') ?>
```

and also set visible on list page for that attribute.

and final out put for your `Iframe`

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo $this->getProduct()->getProductVideo(); ?>?color=ba9344&badge=0" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```